# Background image over div

Tags: html, css, background

I want to make a background image to be seen over div. Anything that I've tried with z-index didn't helped me. Image itself has not standard shape and glowing border. As image ends ideally "logo2" should imitate that "glowing" by box-shadow parameter. But anything I've tried "logo2" always over "logo" crosses the image. This is how I want it to be like site.com/logo2.png

```css
.logo {
    background: url(site.com/logo.png) no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
.logo2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #7b0000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #d09d00;
    position:relative;
 z-index:10;
```

```html
    <div class="logo">
 <div class="logo2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: (../images/logo.png) this image is not loading

Comment: My bad, didn't knew how to do this. Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. You can adjust width of **.logo2** accordingly

```css
.logo {
    background: url(http://homeworld.su/logo.png) no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
.logo2 {
 width: 20%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #7b0000;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #d09d00;
        position:absolute;
        top:10px;
        left:495px;
```

```html
    <div class="logo">
 <div class="logo2"></div>
    </div>
```